# Is there a finitely axiomatizable class of structures whose equality-free theory is not finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

This was originally [an MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410187/is-there-a-finitely-axiomatizable-class-of-structures-whose-equality-free-theory), but I was told to ask it on MathOverflow. Does there exist a class $C$ of $L$-structures for a finite signature $L$, which is finitely axiomatizable in first-order logic with equality, but whose equality-free theory $Th(C)$ is not finitely axiomatizable?

---

*Non-OP edit*: To clarify, the question is whether the finite $\mathsf{FOL}$-axiomatizability of $Th_\mathsf{FOL}(C)$ necessarily implies the finite $\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}$-axiomatizability of $Th_{\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}}(C)$, *regardless* of whether the $\mathsf{FOL}$-deductive closure of $Th_{\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}}(C)$ coincides with $Th_\mathsf{FOL}(C)$ or not. (That is, we don't care whether $Mod(Th_{\mathsf{FOL_{w/o=}}}(C))\not=C.$)

Comment: Are you assuming that the class of structures can be axiomatized by sentences that do not involve equality?

Comment: @JamesHanson No. In fact, the situation is exactly the opposite. If the equality-free theory is not finitely axiomatizable, then the class can't be axiomatized without using equality.

Comment: Oh, I think I see now. You aren't assuming that $Th(C)$ axiomatizes $C$, right?

Comment: @JamesHanson Yeah. Also, by $Th$, I mean the first-order theory without equality, not the standard first-order theory with equality.

Comment: Since this confusion came up with the original version of the question as well (repeatedly!), I've added a clarifying edit.

Comment: Follow-up [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422766/persistent-finite-axiomatizability-relational-edition).

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Emil Jerabek in the comments, the argument for relational languages fails in the last step. However, the question is already answered by the example with function symbols.

**EDIT**: If function symbols are allowed, then this can happen. Let $L=\left\{P, f, a\right\}$, where $P$ is a property symbol, $f$ is a unary function symbol and $a$ is a proper name. Let $C$ be the class of models axiomatized by $P(a)$ and $a=f(a)$.

The equality-free theory of $C$ is axiomatized by $T =\left\{P(a), P(f(a)), P(f(f(a))), ...\right\}$.

In fact, if $M$ is a model of $T$, then a model $N$ of $P(a)\wedge(a=f(a))$ can be obtained from $M$ by taking a quotient (identifying all elements corresponding to $a$, $f(a)$, $f(f(a))$, ... in $M$). The canonical mapping from $M$ to $N$ is elementary for equality-free formulas. Since $N$ is in $C$, $M$ satisfies any equality-free sentence in $C$.

However, $T$ is not finitely axiomatizable.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

If $L$ is relational (and finite), then finite axiomatizability with equality implies finite axiomatizability without equality.

Since $L$ is finite, let $\phi_1(x,\bar{z})$, ..., $\phi_n(x,\bar{z})$ be all atomic formulas (with the exception of equality formulas) in the variables $x$, $\bar{z}=(z_1,...,z_k)$, in which $k+1$ is the greatest relational arity in $L$.

Consider the formula $I(x,y)$ saying that $x$ and $y$ satisfy the same atomic relations:

$\forall\bar{z}((\phi_1(x,\bar{z})\leftrightarrow\phi_1(y,\bar{z}))\wedge...\wedge(\phi_n(x,\bar{z})\leftrightarrow\phi_n(y,\bar{z})))$.

[edit: In the compact notation sugested in the comments,

$I(x,y)$ is $\forall\bar{z}\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}(\phi_i(x,\bar{z})\leftrightarrow\phi_i(y,\bar{z}))$.]

Now, let $A$ be an axiom for $Th_{FOL}(C)$. We may assume that $\bar{z}$ does not occur in $A$. Suppose that $\psi$ is an equality-free sentence such that $\psi\in Th_{FOL}(C)$. Therefore,

$A\vdash\psi$.

If $A_I$ is obtained from $A$ by replacing all occurrences of the form $u=v$ by $I(u,v)$, then

$A_I, \forall x,y(x=y\leftrightarrow I(x,y))\vdash\psi$, by a standard result on equivalence.

Since the equality axioms are consequences of $\forall x,y(x=y\leftrightarrow I(x,y))$, we have that

$A_I, \forall x,y(x=y\leftrightarrow I(x,y))\vdash\psi$ in first-order logic without equality also. Hence,

$A_I\vdash\psi$ in first-order logic without equality by the standard conservativity result on definitional extensions.

Since $A$ implies $A_I$, we conclude that $A_I$ is an axiom for $Th_{FOL_{w/o=}}(C)$.

Comment: I think this can be stated more briefly as: "We can convert a finite axiomatization with equality into a finite axiomatization without equality by replacing $x=y$ in every axiom with $I(x,y)$; any deduction from those axioms will remain valid after making the same replacement throughout." Secondarily, I would reformat the key definition as $$I(x,y) := \forall \bar{z}  \bigwedge_{i=1}^n (\phi_i(x,\bar{z}) \leftrightarrow \phi_i (y,\bar{z}))$$(using the command *\bigwedge*)

Comment: @Matt F. You are right, thanks. There is a minor issue with respect to the preservation of deductions under the appropriate replacements: proofs for the equality axioms must be inserted. I will add the simplified notation. How do you write the endpoints for the bigwedge?

Comment: @RodrigoFreire Identically to "$\sum_{i=1}^n$." Note that, like the summation symbol, the appearance will differ based on the type of line it occurs in: compare $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n$ and $$\bigwedge_{i=1}^n.$$

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, I thought that would work and edited just before your comment.

Comment: This argument for relational theories was my first thought back in April, but it is *wrong*, as $A$ does *not* imply $A_I$ in general. For example, let $A$ be $\exists x,y\,(I(x,y)\land x\ne y)$. Then $A$ is easily seen to axiomatize a *consistent* FO theory with equality, but $A_I=\exists x,y\,(I(x,y)\land\neg I(x,y))$ is inconsistent, hence it does *not* axiomatize the equality-free consequences of $A$, and it is not implied by $A$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think it is worth pointing out that if equality occurs only positively in $A$, then the argument holds.

Comment: Yes, in that case it holds. It also holds if $A$ implies that $x=y$ is equivalent to an $=$-free formula (though in that case it’s easy to prove the result directly, even for nonrelational languages). I wonder if there is a useful more general sufficient condition that would subsume these two cases.

Comment: Anyway, the relational case of the original problem remains an intriguing question, even though your counterexample answers the question as posed by the OP.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think that the following general sufficient condition may be useful: If $M$ satisfies $A$, then the quotient of $M$ by the congruence defined by $I(x,y)$ also satisfies $A$.

Comment: I've gone ahead and [asked this as a separate question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422766/persistent-finite-axiomatizability-relational-edition) (@EmilJeřábek also).